# jQuery unbind/off event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm trying to prevent a memory leak caused by part of the code which doesn't get fired when the element is destroyed.

My code attaches an event to the `document` on `mouseup` and does stuff with a particular element of the DOM.
If the element is removed, the event should be disabled by `willDestroyElement` of Ember but some times it doesn't happens so I need to disable it manually.

To do so I put on the very begin of my event function this string:

```
onMouseUp: function(evt) {
    // relevant part of the code:
    if (!this.$()) {
      return $(document).off(evt);
    }

    [...]
```

In this way looks like the event is correctly unbinded from the `document`.

I can't find documentation about this use case and I'd like to know if doing so could lead to side effects or anything bad?

Comment: Looks clean. I'd logically say no. Still weird you're having problems with the *willDestroyElement*.

Comment: Thanks, yes it's weird, it happens during our tests so it could even be related to how fast our tests are ran or anything else...